# Add observe isn't working in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, observers, nsnotifications

When I was looking how to call a function from another view when this view is dismissing I found out that the NotificationCenter was a good solution so I tried to use it like this:

In my Main view (ViewController) where I want to call the function I put this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(ViewController.loyalty),
            name: NSNotification.Name("loyalty"),
            object: nil)
```

In my Second view before I call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` I call this to trigger the observe:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("loyalty"), object: nil)
```

Finally after the swift 4 update my function `loyalty` has `@objc` before the `func` and it is like this:

```
@objc func loyalty(){
}
```

PS I tried also with NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loyalty")

Maybe I have forgot to do something?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The function was executing after all I forgot to remove some arrays and that's why I thought it was not working.

Comment: Maybe you are removing the observer in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: @the4kman thanks for your comment but I don't remove it (I checked to be sure)

Comment: Are you removing the observer somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @the4kman no I search it with cmd+f to be sure

Comment: @the4kman The function was executing after all but I forgot to erase my arrays to get the correct result. (I found it out with printing at the start of the function). Sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 3):

Apple documentation said :

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.

So I think your controller was deallocated after `dismiss` before it gets a notification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and good information too! The function was executing after all but I forgot to erase my arrays to get the correct result. (I found it out with printing at the start of the function). Sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 2):

I think the function should have a parameter to be called.

Try to edit your function to  :

```
@objc func loyalty(_ notification : NSNotification){
}
```

And the selector becomes `#selector(ViewController.loyalty(_:)`

NB : Both `register`/`post` should be called in the same `Thread`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and good information too! The function was executing after all but I forgot to erase my arrays to get the correct result. (I found it out with printing at the start of the function). Sorry for wasting your time...